# How to track Changes in StreamInSight?

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker, complex-event-processing, streaminsight

In my project i need to track newly inserted rows in database table. And give those rows to .net application for processing.I went through StremInSight, it suits correctly.So What i want to know is are there any options to capture changes in StreamInSight? Otherwise how i can club both ServiceBroker and StremInSight. I Mean Can we use service broker to stream changes to StreamInsight?